# storahci events in event log

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, event-log, diskpart

I'm seeing hundreds of storahci events ID: 129 events lately. Particularly after windows 10 has waken from sleep.

Message is "Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort1, was issued."
There are also evet ID 153 errors: The IO operation at logical block address 0x637d58 for Disk 1 (PDO name: \Device\00000046) was retried.

So sounds like I may have a failing drive. Thing is - which drive. In Diskpart disk1 is my 6TB Seagate NAS drive. But is raidport1 and Disk1 in the events the same as disk 1 in disk part?

Can I be sure the 6TB NAS drive is the suspect drive?

I have a 960 Pro 1tb, a 970 Pro 1tb and an 860 Pro 512 GB drives also. Samsung magician says they are all in good health.

I recently installed Intel Rapid Storage technology driver, but I believe I was getting the errors before that - just not as many. I've had about 50 of them logged in the last hour.

Comment: Have a look at https://superuser.com/q/1376121/213131

Comment: Ok.. This... "In your case the problem is with physical disk 0. The reference to \Device\RaidPort0 doesn't always mean disk 0, but the reference to Disk 0 in the second event (ID 153?) does (which is nice since determining what RaidPort0 refers to involves several steps)."... answers the first part of my question. I've already emptied the drive, run chkdsk, deleted partitions/recreated them and changed sata port and cable. I've had no error 129 or 153 so far today, but if it happens again I'll RMA the drive. Thanks.

Comment: Yup. This question is a duplicate of that but since the answer on the other question isn't upvoted I can't mark it as such.

Comment: Interesting that my searches here, other forums and google did not turn up that question.